Walking through a portal attached to a wall
I have created portals that work perfectly fine. I walk into one and come out the other side seamlessly. The problem I am having, though, is when the portal is up against a wall my player (A CharacterBody3D) can collide with. When I try to walk through the portal, the collision of the wall stops me from going through. What method in Godot could I use to fix this?

Can your portal collider not be just a bit more extended so it is optically on the wall but for collision detection a fraction in front of the wall?

@Zibelas That would work (I tried it out), but it doesn't make it as seamless, and I want you to be able to stand halfway in the portal without being teleported.

My idea was to maybe be able to subtract a certain area from a collision shape. (Kind of what you can do with a CSG Mesh)

This answer was written for Unity, but it would be worth checking whether Godot has a similar API to temporarily ignore contacts between a pair of colliders, without literally punching a hole in the mesh (which can be expensive and error prone).

@DMGregory Thank you! Do you think I could use Collision Layers and Masks at all for this?

I think that the video game portal made it like so: If you have a portal on a portalable wall, that whole wall (all portalable surfaces touching each other, as you don't want unportalable walls to be affected) gets tagged, let's say "PortalWall". If you normally walk into the wall, it behaves normally. If you are in a certain range of the portal (Standing in/just outside a portal) the wall becomes non-collidable. An issue might be that if a player stood inside the portals with both in the air, he would fall through the wall. I would fix this by adding an invisible platform under the portals

@CheckerT Thank you! This is exactly what I ended up doing, except I just disabled the collision layer on the player to not make it collide with any walls, and enabled the collision layer to make it only collide with the invisible platform under the portal (and some small colliders at the edges of the portal to prevent clipping through the wall.
